# How to call a flask function from server using onBlur in HTML?

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-socketio

I'm new to Flask and I am trying to make a simple signup page. Here is the code-

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}

<div class="container">
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('signup') }}">

                <label for="user">Username </label>
                <input type="text" id="user" name="user" onblur='NameCheck()'>

               <i id='acceptIC' class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>


                <label for="pas">Password </label>
                <input type="password" id="pas" name="pas">


                <label for="mail">Email ID </label>
                <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail">

            <button type="submit">Signup</button>
        </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I wish to display a font awesome icon next to the username as soon as it looses focus, this icon is green if the username is available (database in MongoDB) and red if it isn't.

Comment: `onblur` is JavaScript and has nothing to do with Flask. You basically need to setup JavaScript event handler for 'onblur`.

Comment: Alright, and can I trigger an external Python script from it? If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: Of course yes. When you submit a html POST form, you will need to setup the Flask route to handle it. Something like `@app.route("signup", methods=['POST'])`.

Comment: Read the "Accessing Request Data" section [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @hcheung but I want to trigger the function before the user submits the form. Like a auto check for available Usernames.

Comment: That is also no problem. Just use an Ajax call to your route and you are fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be achived by using flask-socketio in your onBlur call a javascript function like-

```
function NameCheck(data) {
if (data !== '') {
    sock.emit('name_check', data);
    sock.on('responded', function (msg) {
        if (msg) {
            document.getElementById('acceptIC').style['display'] = 'flex';
           }
    });
}
}
```

In flask socketio call

```
@socketio.on('name_check')
def handle_name(data):
    socketio.emit('responded', Mongo.checkUser(data))
```

where

```
Mongo.checkUser(data)
```

is your required function. Returns a bool value